# scoped route pointing to the wrong controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In order to make url like http://example.com/:username I've built my route for my user show action like the following:

```
scope ':username' do
  get '' => 'users#show', as: :user
end
```

(for info here is my user model to_param method)

```
def to_param
  username
end
```

In order to prevent access to other controllers by this route I've added all my other routes before this one. It seems to work except for this one:

```
get 'search/:query' => 'searches#show', as: :search
```

where is my form:

```
  = form_tag search_path(query: {} || params[:query]), method: :get do
    = text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control"
    = submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

I don't know why but it always pointing to the user show action. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why have you used a scope? You could do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
get ':username', to: 'users#show', as: :user
```

---

**Search**

The problem with your search function is `method: :get`

When you send a `GET` request through HTTP, your URL basically looks like this:

```
http://domain.com/search?query=your+search+query
```

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

You'd be better sending a `POST` request, like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
post 'search/:query', to: 'searches#show', as: :search

#view
 = form_tag search_path(query: {} || params[:query]), method: :post do
    = text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control"
    = submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explaination Rich. Basically I have other routes in my scope, I've just show this one for my example. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem - hope it helps you!